# How to put input within the actual table

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup generated by an UI-framework:

```
<table style="display: inline; border: 1px solid black;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="n" value="" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vx02m2c/)

As you can see in the demo, the input field is not in the table. I need to put that input strictly within the table borders as follows:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: remove `display:inline` property from your table `style` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`display: inline` stops the table acting as a table and implicitly generates an anonymous block table (to hold the table row) inside the inline box.

Don't do that. Putting blocks inside inline boxes is ugly.

Use `inline-table` instead if you want an inline table.

Comment: instead of inline-table u also could wrap a layer like div (inline-block) or a span witch is already inline around it

Comment: Putting a span around it would cause a very similar problem. There's no need to add additional markup at all though.

Comment: U r right, but could be very usefull for future styling. Also other ways could do the trick like floating